# wpf complete reference

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, documentation

I am looking for a complete wpf tags documentation to use it with wpf controls.
Anybody seen something like this?

10x

Comment: You mean XAML tags. WPF is the whole technology, the markup format is XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746683.aspx) feels a little mechanical, but it's complete.

Comment: XAML tags are used for assigning properties on WPF controls. Lookup the WPF control the XAML refers to and read about the properties on the control in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Tags" complete documentation for WPF. The markup - XAML - is infinite by it's very nature. If I create a new control, boom, I can use it in XAML. Or, I can use XAML to create my own arbitrary object graph using custom types that are nothing related to UI.

There is a XAML language spec, but that is not what you looking for. The answer from BC for the MSDN is a start, but vastly incomplete. Look at everything under System.Windows.Controls* for a better idea.